# Crazy crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS with in-app purchase on iPhone

Tags: ios, crash, in-app-purchase, crash-reports, storekit

Can't fix strange crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` with in-app purchase on iPhone. It presents on all my applications with different architecture. It doesn't depend on iOS version or device. What can cause the issue?

[image: strange crash with in-app purchases]

The full code to process in-app purchases on the application:

```
#pragma mark In-App Purchase

- (NSString*)getProductId:(NSString*)feature {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
    NSString *bundleIdentifier = [info objectForKey: @"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:feature, [bundleIdentifier stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]];
}

- (void)requestItems:(NSString*)feature {
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:[self getProductId:feature]];
    if ([feature isEqualToString:g100Items]) {
        if (product100ItemsRequest) {
            [product100ItemsRequest release];
            product100ItemsRequest = nil;
        }
        product100ItemsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
        product100ItemsRequest.delegate = self;
        [product100ItemsRequest start];
        // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
    } else
        if ([feature isEqualToString:gUnlimitedItems]) {
            if (productUnlimitedItemsRequest) {
                [productUnlimitedItemsRequest release];
                productUnlimitedItemsRequest = nil;
            }
            productUnlimitedItemsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
            productUnlimitedItemsRequest.delegate = self;
            [productUnlimitedItemsRequest start];
            // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
        }
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    [products addObjectsFromArray:response.products];
    for (SKProduct *product in response.products) {
        if (product && [product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:g100Items]]) {
            [button100Items setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:g100ItemsButton, product.localizedPrice] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            // finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestItems
            [product100ItemsRequest release];
            product100ItemsRequest = nil;
        }
        if (product && [product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:gUnlimitedItems]]) {
            [buttonUnlimitedItems setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:gUnlimitedItemsButton, product.localizedPrice] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            // finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestItems
            [productUnlimitedItemsRequest release];
            productUnlimitedItemsRequest = nil;
        }
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}

// call this method once on startup
- (void)loadStore:(BOOL)tryAgain {
    if (tryAgain) {
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
        NSMutableArray *oldProducts = products;
        products = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil] retain];
        [oldProducts release];
    }
    // restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    // get the product description (defined in early sections)
    [self requestItems:g100Items];
    [self requestItems:gUnlimitedItems];
}

// call this before making a purchase
- (BOOL)canMakePurchases {
    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

// kick off the upgrade transaction
- (void)purchaseItems:(NSString*)feature {
    bool ok = false;
    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:feature]]) {
            SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
            if (payment) {
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
                // Calling AppStore Dialog
            }
            ok = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!ok) {
        [self loadStore:YES];
        [self showAlert:gInAppAlertTitle alertStr:gNoProductsToMakePurchase];
        return;
    }
}

// saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:g100Items]]) {
        // save the transaction receipt to disk
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]]/*transaction.transactionReceipt*/ forKey:[self getProductId:g100Items]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    } else
        if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:gUnlimitedItems]]) {
            // save the transaction receipt to disk
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]]/*transaction.transactionReceipt*/ forKey:[self getProductId:gUnlimitedItems]];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
}

// enable pro features
- (bool)provideContent:(NSString *)productId {
    if (productId) {
        FirstViewController* firstViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:gSourceTabIndex];

        if ([productId isEqualToString:[self getProductId:g100Items]]) {
            firstViewController.itemCount += 100;
            [firstViewController saveItems];
            // 100 Items Provided
            return true;
        } else
            if ([productId isEqualToString:[self getProductId:gUnlimitedItems]]) {
                firstViewController.itemCount = gItemUnlimitedCount;
                [firstViewController saveItems];
                // Unlimited Items Provided
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}

// removes the transaction from the queue and posts a notification with the transaction result
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful {
    // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
    if (wasSuccessful) {
        // send out a notification that we’ve finished the transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
    else {
        // send out a notification for the failed transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
}

// called when the transaction was successful
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [self recordTransaction:transaction];
    bool provided = [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

// called when a transaction has been restored and successfully completed
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [self recordTransaction:transaction.originalTransaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

// called when a transaction has failed
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
        // error!
        [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
        [self showAlert:gInAppAlertTitle alertStr:[transaction.error localizedDescription]];
    } else {
        // this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}

// called when the transaction status is updated
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)process100Items:(id)sender {
    if ([self canMakePurchases]) {
        [self purchaseItems:g100Items];
    } else {
        [self showAlert:gInAppAlertTitle alertStr:gCanNotMakePurchases];
    }
    // Buy 100 Items Button Pressed
}

- (IBAction)processUnlimitedItems:(id)sender {
    if ([self canMakePurchases]) {
        [self purchaseItems:gUnlimitedItems];
    } else {
        [self showAlert:gInAppAlertTitle alertStr:gCanNotMakePurchases];
    }
    // Buy Unlimited Items Button Pressed
}

- (IBAction)restoreCompletedTransactions:(id)sender {
    if ([products count] == 0) {
        [self loadStore:YES];
        [self showAlert:gInAppAlertTitle alertStr:gNoProductsToMakePurchase];
        return;
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

And one more crash log for example:

[image: strange crash with in-app purchases]

The project doesn't use ARC. I can't reproduce the issue on my devices.

### UPDATED

On the first application `self` in delegate property is `@interface FourthViewController : UIViewController` as part of `UITabViewController` on .xib form. It's loading to the memory when user selects the tab. And I never saw that it was unloaded from the memory.

On the second application `self` in delegate property is `@interface SettingsView : UIViewController`. It's loading to the memory by the code of class `@interface RootViewController : UIViewController`:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        me = self;
        settingsView = [[SettingsView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [settingsView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The parent class is loading to the memory by the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:getDeviceBounds] autorelease];
    RootViewController *rc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.window setRootViewController:rc];
    root = rc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

And I've found the code:

```
- (void)restartApp {
    RootViewController *toRemove = root;
    RootViewController *rc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.window setRootViewController:rc];
    root = rc;
    [toRemove release];
}
```

So, I can fix the error on the second application. But I don't sure about the first application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is most likely happening is your delegate is already deallocated. The delegate for `SKProductsRequest` is defined as

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<SKProductsRequestDelegate> delegate;
```

Since it is `assign`, it means it neither retains the delegate, nor will it be `nil` when the delegate is released.

You do not indicate which class this code is from, but I can see that the delegate is `self`.

I would recommend you set a breakpoint or add an `NSLog` to the class' `dealloc`. This way you can find out if this is indeed the case (the delegate is being deallocated) and then figure out who is freeing it.

A common mistake people make is to make the delegate a UIKit object, like a UIView or UIViewController. When the screen changes, that object is dealloc'd and the delegate when the request is completed is now no longer valid.

Comment: Wouldn't declaring the `delegate` as `weak` solve this?

Comment: Yes, that would be the ideal way to address it. My bad for not explicitly mentioning it.